# Can't enable apache mod on emerge

Tags: apache-http-server, gentoo

I want to add mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http to Apache server on my Gentoo, but apparently some file with high priority on the system is disabling the mods and preventing me to install.

I am currently editing `/usr/portage/profiles/base/make.defaults` file, but it gets updated (and changes lost) every time I update the system. I have to edit it every time I update the system/reinstall Apache.

Besides that, I have already added dependencies to the `/etc/portage/package.use` file:

```
www-servers/apache proxy proxy_http
```

What other files do I have do change or should check flags so I can enable proxy and do not have to edit files again every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${PORTDIR}/profiles/base/make.defaults` is not intended for user editing. (One hint that this is the case is that the path name starts with `/usr` and doesn’t include `/local` in it.) Instead, you should edit `/etc/portage/make.conf` (or, if you have an old install and haven’t moved `make.conf` yet, `/etc/make.conf`). Note that if you are merely trying to add a few modules through the `APACHE2_MODULES` variable, you can reference the original variable’s value using `sh`-like notation of `${APACHE2_MODULES}`. (Such a reference is necessary because, unlike `USE`, `APACHE2_MODULES` is *not* an incremental `make.conf` variable.) In `/etc/portage/make.conf`:

```
APACHE2_MODULES="${APACHE2_MODULES} proxy proxy_http"
```

For further information on `make.conf`, view the manpage installed by portage on your local system with `$ man 5 make.conf`

As you referenced `/etc/portage/package.use`, note that you *can* also configure these flags via `package.use`. Note, however, that `APACHE2_MODULES` is a “`USE_EXPAND`” variable. This means that any values you set it to in `make.conf` will automatically be prefixed with `apache2_modules_` (the variable’s name in lowercase plus an underscore). Thus, you could also make your changes with the following entry in `package.use`:

```
www-servers/apache apache2_modules_proxy apache2_modules_proxy_http
```

A `USE_EXPAND` variable’s expansion is a real useflag. That is, `apache2_modules_proxy` is an actual normal useflag that `www-servers/apache` accepts. If you specify use flags of `proxy` and proxy_http`, portage just silently ignores those because`www-servers/apache` does not define/accept such useflags.

Comment: Okay, it worked, thanks! I opted for the second approach as most packages were configured on `package.use` and the `make.conf` file was still untouched.